# "-Xlint:unchecked" not working after configured in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have configured `-Xlint:unchecked` in the setting of IntelliJ. I configured `-Xlint:unchecked` in "Additional command line parameters" in Java Complier.
But when I run `-Xlint:unchecked` in terminal, the terminal always shows `command not found: -Xlint:unchecked`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify the issue. What is the full command that you run in the terminal? Why do you need to run it in the terminal?

Comment: The full command is `-Xlint:unchecked`. I run it for the warning of unchecked error.

Comment: `-Xlint:unchecked` isn't found because it isn't a command meant to be run on its own. It's a compiler flag for modifying the behavior of the `javac` executable. The normal usage from command line would be `javac <foo>.java -Xlint:unchecked` where `<foo>` is the name of your source file.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks for comments. May I know `<foo>` is the full-project name or the name of the java file that I want to check?